# How to set the output of sh to a Groovy variable?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-workflow

Is it possible to have the output of the `sh` command be set to a Groovy variable? It seems to be setting it to the status of the command instead.

Example input:

```
node {
   stage "Current Date"
   def curDate = sh "date"
   echo "The current date is ${curDate}"
}
```

Results in the following output:

```
Entering stage Current Date
Proceeding
[Pipeline] sh
[workspace] Running shell script
+ date
Tue May 10 01:15:05 UTC 2016
[Pipeline] echo
The current date is 0
```

It is showing `The current date is 0`, I want it to show `The current date is Tue May 10 01:15:05 UTC 2016` which you can see has been output by the sh command. Am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, `sh` is returning the exit status. Currently your best bet is:

```
sh 'date > outFile'
curDate = readFile 'outFile'
echo "The current date is ${curDate}"
```

ADDENDUM: after this answer was written a new option was added to the `sh` step, use `returnStdout: true` to get the result string from the `sh` call.

Comment: Ah ok, that's a good workaround. It feels like `sh` should support using stdout as output; but then again, I don't know even close to enough about Groovy to have an opinion on design decisions like that. Thanks for the response.

Comment: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26133 is in progress by the way. It would cover this use case.

Comment: Question is older but I am using something like this,  `sh(script: "date", returnStdout: true).toString().trim()`